# Could somebody recomends a good book or article about numerical methods for Stochastic Partial Differential Equations

Tags: pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis, stochastic-processes

Could somebody recomend a good book or article about numerical methods for Stochastic Partial Differential Equations.  I'm looking for  a good introductory material thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend

[**An Introduction to Computational Stochastic PDEs**
by Gabriel J. Lord, Catherine E. Powell, Tony Shardlow.](http://www.cambridge.org/sa/academic/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/introduction-computational-stochastic-pdes?format=HB)